# Missing programFiles/java when trying to publish rn app

Tags: android, react-native

okay, when i wanna publish my reactNative app and see the [docs](https://reactnative.dev/docs/signed-apk-android) i'm stuck on the first step.

> You can generate a private signing key using keytool. On Windows
> keytool must be run from C:\Program Files\Java\jdkx.x.x_x\bin.

when i see my programfiles, there is no java folder there. Am i need android studio to get this, or installing something? please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`C:\Program Files`  for 64bit installation

`C:\Program Files (x86)` for 32bit installation

or search java  C drive

or you need to install java SE from oracle